# django forms with ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django

After researching for days I'm still confused with creating a form involving 4 tables which are all connected via ForiegnKey. I'm not even sure if I'm using the right approach.

Should I use forms.Form or ModelForm? What I'm looking for I'm sure is common but all of my attempts are in vain. It seems like I'm making this more complicated than it should be since all 4 tables are related.

**To the Point:** To create a workorder, pick a Building, then pick a Unit within that Building, then pick a caller from Tenant(s) within that Unit. Then gather all data in view and save WorkOrder.

Using Django 1.6

```
# models.py
class Building(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name


class Unit(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Building)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.unit

class Tenant(models.Model):
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
    name = models.ForeignKey(Building)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)


class WorkOrder(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Building)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
    ordernum = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.unit
```

forms.py

```
# forms.py

class WorkOrderForm(forms.Form):
    building_choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Building.objects.all(),
                                             empty_label='Pick a building',
                                             )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WorkOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['building_choice'].label = 'Building'


    unit_choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Unit.objects.(????),
                                         empty_label='Pick a unit',
                                         )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WorkOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['unit_choice'].label = 'Unit'

    caller_choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tenant.objects.(????),
                                       empty_label='Who called',
                                       )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WorkOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['caller_choice'].label = 'Tenant'
```

views.py (incomplete)

```
#views.py
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WorkOrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            workorder = WorkOrder(name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
                                 unit=form.cleaned_data['unit'],
                                 call_date=form.cleaned_data['call_date'],
                                 caller=form.cleaned_data['caller'],
                                 problem_desc=form.cleaned_data['problem_desc'])
            workorder.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/workorder/')
    else:
        form = WorkOrderForm()
    return render(request, 'workorder_form.html', {'form': form})
```

If someone could let me know the correct way to go about this I'd be forever grateful.

Comment: I would definitely use a `ModelForm`. That way you can just call `form.save()` rather than what you are doing in `if form.is_valid()`. As far as filtering the choices based on other choices, you cannot do that until the user selects something. You could do ajax requests to get the lists. (units for a building when a user selects a building for example)

Comment: thanks for the help, that narrow it down. would creating individual forms help me with the selecting?

Comment: No I wouldn't do that. You could just filter the units based on the current building in the form. And if nothing is selected yet for the building, use an empty queryset. Then just post the form when the user selects a building. But I don't think that would be a nice as an ajax solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I went to the monthly Python/Django Project Night Monday in Boston and showed a few people my feeble attempts. They all agreed to do what you said. JavaScript/jQuery Ajax. I'm obviously new to Django and so far understanding and creating forms has been the number one ass-kicker. I'll never get those tortuous two weeks back

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I posted this question but I found a django package [django-clever-selects](https://github.com/PragmaticMates/django-clever-selects) that met my needs. The docs and example project were well commented. Thanks to all that helped mr earlier.